# Consuming Windows Service from UWP App

Tags: uwp, windows-services, desktop-bridge

I am trying to convert my Win Forms UI to UWP app. The existing Win Forms application talks to my windows services. Is it possible to access my windows service from UWP app?

Comment: I don't see why you can't. Utilize ```System.Net.Http.HttpClient``` and a Serialization library like ```Json.Net``` to get responses and parse them to objects.

Comment: Can you please update us with the approach you took for your solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can communicate with the Windows Service from a UWP application in various ways (including sockets or RPC) but you will not be able to distribute your Windows Service in the Windows Store. This would be OK for an enterprise solution where the Service is installed via some other mechanism.

For sockets or HTTP, you need to make sure the UWP app is able to [communicate to `localhost`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap4-loopbackaccessrules) and also that the [network isolation is removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj835817(v=win.10)). For RPC, you need to make sure your endpoints are [ACLed appropriately for your UWP app's SID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448541(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: if we've a Winforms/WPF app communicating with a windows service (ASP.Net Core)  in  the desktop-bridge,  can't  distribute  both in the Windows Store?  this should be better to change.

Comment: I believe you can ship an ASP.NET Core service as part of a Desktop Bridge app as long as you don't run on port 80. I assumed the original post was about a Windows Service, which isn't currently supported.

Comment: The [ASP.Net Core 2.1  can run  as windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1) listening in localhost:some port (not 80). I need it as an API maybe for more than one applications.  Do you think that I can  distribute  it and install it as windows service via the windows store?

Comment: If I can't currently distribute the ASP.Net Core service as part of the Desktop Bridge app  and install it as windows service, how  the app (which will expose the API for itself usage and maybe for other apps)  could automatically start after reboots and be unique for all users logins?

Comment: It can't run as a Windows Service in the Desktop Bridge, but it can run from the command line.